# is G necessarily injective? Give a proof or a counterexample.

Tags: functions, proof-writing, examples-counterexamples

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets, and let $S \subseteq A$ be a subset. Let $F: S\to B$ be a function , and let $G:A\to B$ be an extension of $F$. suppose that $F$ is injective . is $G$ necessarily injective? Give a proof or a counterexample.

I am very confused please help , thanks

Comment: Simple answer no $G$ is not necessarily injective. Juste define $G(x)$ to be the same for every $x\in A\backslash S$

Answer (score 0):

Let's make this concrete.

Consider $S= \{1, 2, 3\}$, $A = \{1,2, 3,4, 5\}$ and $B = \{11, 12, 13\}$.

Define $F(i) = i+10$ for $i \in S$. We can extend $F$ to some function $G$. Now, $G$ can take any values for $4, 5$.

Play around with this concrete example and see what you think.

In general, if you're struggling with a problem or some abstract idea, try to make it concrete. Make a simple example and see what the properties are.